# LangChainJS ZepMemory and conversationChain prompt object not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, langchain

Im having some issues using ZepMemory and the prompt feature in the ConversationChain class

It appears to be because the _getRole function dosnt exist for the message entries in the ZepMemory.chatHistory class

```
const memory = new ZepMemory({
      sessionId: dynamicSessionId,
      baseURL: cfg.zepUrl
    })
    const model = new ChatOpenAI({
      modelName: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      temperature: 0,
      openAIApiKey: cfg.openaikey
    })
    const chain = new ConversationChain({
      prompt: chatPrompt,
      memory,
      llm: model
    })
```

When setting the prompt in the ConversationChain it gives me an error when run:

`Unhandled Exception: TypeError: message._getType is not a function`

in

`langchain/dist/chat_models/openai.js:252:51`

However when not setting the prompt it works just fine

my chatPrompt looks like this:

```
        const chatPrompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromPromptMessages([
          SystemMessagePromptTemplate.fromTemplate(
// prompt
          ),
          new MessagesPlaceholder('history'),
          HumanMessagePromptTemplate.fromTemplate('{input}')
        ])
```

Im using langchain 0.0.89 & node v v19.6.0

Am i missing something super obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Set returnMessages: true - it's generally required when using memory with chat models

```
const memory = new ZepMemory({
sessionId: dynamicSessionId,
baseURL: zepUrl,
returnMessages: true
})
```

Credit to jacoblee93 on the LangChain Discord Server