# Langchain BufferMemory + ChatPromptTemplate not working

Tags: javascript, openai-api, langchain

The following code sets a new chain using a bufferMemory connected to Redis and a simply prompt.It does not work.

```
const memory = new BufferMemory({
    chatHistory: new RedisChatMessageHistory({
      sessionId: "123",
      sessionTTL: 300,
      config: {
        URL: "", 
      },
    }),
    memoryKey: "history",
  });

  const chatPrompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromPromptMessages([
    SystemMessagePromptTemplate.fromTemplate(
      "my prompt."
    ),
    new MessagesPlaceholder("history"),
    HumanMessagePromptTemplate.fromTemplate("{input}"),
  ]);

  const chain = new ConversationChain({
    memory,
    prompt: chatPrompt,
    llm: model,
  });

  const response = await chain.call({
    input: req.question,
  });
```

If I remove the prompt from the ConversaitonChain it works fine, so I know I'm missing something with the history fetching/merging but I can't figure out what.

The error is not helpful -
'message._getType is not a function'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same challenge but from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76393974/langchainjs-zepmemory-and-conversationchain-prompt-object-not-working) thread, I was able to fix it.
Apparently, you need to update your code like:

```
const memory = new BufferMemory({
    chatHistory: new RedisChatMessageHistory({
      sessionId: "123",
      sessionTTL: 300,
      config: {
        URL: "", 
      },
    }),
    memoryKey: "history",
    //Add this
    returnMessages: true
  });
```

After that, adding the prompt to the ConversaitonChain works well.